# API to get network traffic info on iphone

Tags: iphone, networking, traffic

now i want to get some network traffic info on iphone, like realtime bytes in per second and so on, so does there any api can do such thing, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You could capture with tcpdump and feed to wireshark to get this: http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChStatSummary.html See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166044/how-can-i-configure-wireshark-to-see-https-traffic/7166278#7166278 about tcpdump. If you want it from code, you'll have to count bytes at NSURLConnectionDelegate's connection:didReceiveData:

Answer (score 0):

I am exploring this area as well. It seems like one could (at least) leverage the NSURLConnectionDelegate mechanisms to infer application-perceived throughput over time. It would be nice if there were something cleaner...